# && condition for while loop will always stop when one statement is true

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I wrote this code in java (purpose is "the hunugry duck part 1" puzzle from codeingame.com):

```
while (indexH > 0 && indexW > 0) {
        if (indexH -1 >= 0 && indexW-1 >= 0 && foodArray[indexH - 1][indexW] > foodArray[indexH][indexW-1]) { 
            indexH--;
            highestFood += foodArray[indexH][indexW];
        } else if (indexW -1 >= 0 && indexH-1 >= 0 && foodArray[indexH][indexW] > foodArray[indexH-1][indexW] ) { 
            indexW--;
            highestFood += foodArray[indexH][indexW];
        } else {
            if (indexH == 0) {
                indexW--;
                highestFood += foodArray[indexH][indexW];
            } else if(indexW == 0) {
                indexH--;
                highestFood += foodArray[indexH][indexW];
            }
        }
    }
```

the problem is, if either indexW or indexH reaches 0 the while loop will stop what it clearly should not do. Can you tell me why this is behaving like that.

Comment: which one ?? there are multiple `&&` conditions

Comment: "And" means both conditions must be true, just like in English ("you must do this and that" compared with "you must do this or that").

Comment: which one ? the condition for the while loop. I just see one, tell me if you see more than one condition for a while loop.
"And" is correct. It will reach the case that both indexes are 0 so it should stop the while loop. the problem is that if either reaches 0 (like | | ) it will cancel the while loop. I dont think you understood my problem. My goal is that both indexW and indexH have to be 0 to cancel the while loop not either of them. even if I use the && if one of them reaches 0, even if the other one not 0 and positive, it will cancel the loop.

Comment: *"It will reach the case that both indexes are 0 so it should stop the while loop"* - That assumption is nonsense. ***You*** wrote the `while` to loop as long as ___both___ values are larger than 0. Of course it will stop when one doesn't satisfy that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it should run even if either of indexW or indexH reaches 0, then you should use or

```
while (indexH > 0 || indexW > 0) {
```

or

&& will return false if any one of the condition is false i.e. if only one is true

To exit the loop only if both values equals zero, then you should do this

```
while (indexH != 0 || indexW != 0) {
```

Comment: see the updated answer @JSStift

Comment: thank you. this solved my problem